# styled maps with google maps v3 - how to set the water color on the landscape geometry?

Tags: google-maps

i am upgrading my code to the google map API v3, i was using an overlay to apply my own style but now i was trying to use the styled maps which are much faster.

i am getting pretty well getting the appearance i like, the only thing i can't do is to set the color for the water feature only inside the landscape. which means basically the color of lakes and rivers. i need a neat map with nothing and a flat color, but the lakes and rivers don't look good like this.

i have been playing with the styled map wizard but couldn't find an easy way: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to distinguish lakes and rivers from seas and oceans.  According to the [MapTypeStyleFeatureType](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MapTypeStyleFeatureType) spec, all you have is:

> *water*   - Apply the rule to bodies of water.

Not sure if the data model supports it, but there is no harm in asking with a [feature request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Maps%20API%20v3%20-%20Feature%20Request).