# How can I hide rivers and lakes in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm having some trouble styling this map, I'd like to show GB, and colour the whole of it.

To achieve that, I'm not showing the water, but that's making rivers and lakes to show inside the island.

If I'm not mistaken there's no way to style oceans/seas differently from rivers/lakes, so any ideas of how to do this?

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fxt8D/) will make it clearer.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: lets go this is picnic spot.... :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610436/styled-maps-with-google-maps-v3-how-to-set-the-water-color-on-the-landscape-ge/3614561#3614561

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer says in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610436/styled-maps-with-google-maps-v3-how-to-set-the-water-color-on-the-landscape-ge/3614561#3614561) provided in the comments, there is no way of differentiating between different water bodies as far as styling goes. They are all classified as `water`. In your case however, if you can get a shapefile of GB that is the same projection as Google Maps ([Mercator](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#WorldCoordinates)) and convert it to an image - you can use this as a custom overlay on your google maps. And based on however you styled your shapefile, this is what you'll see on the maps (so in your case you should make the layer a a solid color before converting it to an image). For custom overlays on google maps see here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays